# SSH and PHP different behavior

Tags: php, node.js, shell, ssh, phantomjs

I installed [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) via [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/) on my remote server and added this to .bashrc: `PATH=~/node/bin:$PATH`
If I run `phantomjs -v` in ssh console then I get the expected result: `1.9.7`

Now when I'm trying to use it in PHP script:

```
<?
putenv("PATH=~/node/bin:$_ENV[PATH]");
echo shell_exec('echo $PATH');
echo shell_exec('phantomjs -v 2>&1');
```

I get this error (and it's not `sh: phantomjs: command not found`):

```
~/node/bin:/bin:/usr/bin  
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I can use the full path `~/node/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs` to get the correct response.

But the question is: why do php exec() and console behave differently?
Is that because some sh/bash? And maybe they are using different ENV?

Comment: Add `echo $_ENV['HOME']`. Also `echo shell_exec('whoami')`. Could be illuminating. (`~` might not be what you think it is.)

Comment: `$_ENV['HOME']` = Undefined index; `whoami` is my username on shared hosting for both ssh and php; `~` is /home/user

Comment: Did you try it in both your shell and your web page? If it's not that, I'm drawing a blank. (Also, apparently it's `getenv('HOME')`, `$_ENV['HOME']` is indeed "not it".

Comment: shell returns `/home/user` for `echo $HOME`

Comment: php returns nothing for `getenv('HOME')`, after adding `putenv("HOME=~")` it returns `sh: phantomjs: command not found`

Comment: `putenv('HOME=~')` is like explaining "oneiromancy" as "the thing that oneiromancer does". `~` gets its meaning from `HOME`, you can't define `HOME` by `~`.

Comment: :) without defining it returns nothing, `putenv("HOME=/home/user")` doesn't change anything (and we already decided that it's not it). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59075/discussion-between-mu3-and-amadan).

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs as different user, `apache`, or `nginx`. Those users hasn't homedir, so path `~/node/bin` doesn't exists. Please add to PATH global path to nodejs, and run your script after.

Comment: Please check comments, it's the same user with `/home/<user>` home directory. Both return `node npm phantomjs` for `ls ~/node/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Scripts for node.js or PHP or even CRON, use FULL PATH names to avoid these errors. Depending on your config, PHP runs as user "www-data" (eg: ubuntu) or "nobody". Hence the paths doesn't exists.

Note: if you look into /etc/ folder, you can see examples of scripts which uses FULL PATHS

Answer (score 0):

`shell_exec` does not get ENV vars from the current process.

You can use `passthru` for this though

```
putenv("HELLO=world");
passthru("echo \$HELLO");
// world
```

It's worth noting that `passthru` also receives STDIN and writes directly to STDOUT and STDERR

Comment: It does get. `putenv('HELLO=world'); echo exec('echo $HELLO');` returns `world`

Comment: But `putenv()` doesn't use vars defined by itself. `putenv('H=/home/user');putenv('PATH=$H/node/bin');echo exec('echo $PATH');` returns `$H/node/bin`